# How to handle jquery $.getJSON request in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, getjson

I'm somewhat new to CodeIgniter and jQuery so I need a little input on how to handle this Ajax request, get the data, and pass it to the controller to be used effectively.

Here is my $.getJSON request in my js prototype...

```
$.getJSON('/ci/ajaxCustom/ajaxCustomerSearch', 'keyword=' + $('#contactKeyword').val(), function(json) {
 *I'm assuming I now have a javascript array named json*
        });
```

My Ajax function prepares the data this way...

```
$variablearray = array($rsCount, $keyword, $firstNameKW, $lastNameKW, $ldPhoneKW, $emailKW);
            $arr = array_merge((array)$variablearray, (array)$contactarray);
            $json = json_encode($arr);
```

Am I correct to assume I now have a javascript array of data that I can use throughout my application by accessing the elements of the array through the js object?

Comment: You have the object after the ajax call returns; that is, in code in the callback or code called by code in the callback. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  Is that possible or can ajax only return html?

Comment: When you use `getJSON`, jQuery will expect the response to actually be valid JSON and then it'll convert it for you. The parameter passed to the callback will be a ready-to-use JavaScript object (unless the JSON has syntax errors, in which case it'll throw an error).